# Optimized way of getting values from an erlang process loop

Tags: erlang

Hi I'm a newbie in Erlang and I just started learning about processes. Here I have a typical process loop:

```
loop(X,Y,Z) ->
    receive
        {do} ->
            NewX = X+1,
            NewY = Y+1,
            NewZ = Z+1,

            Product = NewX * NewY * NewZ,

            % do something

            loop(NewX,NewY,NewZ)
    end.
```

How do I get the latest value of `Product` from a function let's say `get_product()`? I know that message passing will be the logical option but is there a more optimal way of extracting the value?

Comment: Don't know if it was you, who asked this very question recently. But I will just quote myself: `you **must not** worry about performance, until it is proved to perform not efficient enough`. Having said this, what is the exact performance you expect? Do you need to get `Product` `n` times in `t` secs and messages aren't fast enough? Or, is there any other performance test you need to pass? Also, I don't think there is a faster way to communicate to other process inside a single Erlang VM. Though, it might be faster to use sockets directly if there is network between processes.

Comment: An instance where loop is spawned n hundreds of times and 5n values to extract from all of the processes at once, time would be as fast as possible depending on the performance of each. Anyaway loop/3 is just a simplified version, I was expecting for a simple way or any benchmark that compares the message pass method or an existing BIF that "I do not know", that extracts these values. Also, I don't remember asking this just recently.

Comment: BTW Product is not stored in the loop state in your example, so you'll have to make the evaluation in the get_product as shown in Ning example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are methods to communicate between Erlang processes I am aware of, and my (possibly wrong) assessment of theirs relative performance.

1. **[Message passing](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#id67007)**. This method will suit most of your needs. I don't know how it is actually implemented, but from my point of view it should be as fast as putting a pointer into a queue and retrieving it back.
2. **Exterior methods, e.g. [sockets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html), [files](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html), [pipes](http://www.erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#id49435)**. These methods might be faster for communicating between different nodes, depending on a problem you solve, your solution and environment your program will be executed in. Inter-node communication in Erlang is done via TCP connections, so if you want to use self written code to communicate via TCP sockets, you should try really hard to outperform Erlang's implementation.
3. **[ETS](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html), [Dets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html)**. These methods won't be faster than message passing (ETS) or file (Dets) assuming best possible implementation.
4. **[NIF](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html)**. You can write one method to save value in your NIF library and one to retrieve it. This one has a potential to outperform message passing since you can just save a value into a variable and return it back when needed and it has no overhead on pattern matching in `receive`.
5. **[Process dictionary](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced.html#dict)**. You can get another process dictionary using `erlang:process_info(Pid, dictionary)` call, in the `Pid` process you can put value in that dictionary using `put(Key, Value)` call.

Also, if you want to speed up your Erlang application take a look at [HiPE](http://erlang.org/doc/man/HiPE_app.html), it might help.

Before switching from message passing to anything from this list to gain in speed you should **measure it first**!

Answer (score 2):

I *assumed* this is what you want:

```
-module(lab).

-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    InitialState = {1,1,1},
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [InitialState]),
    register(server, Pid).

loop(State) ->
    {X, Y, Z} = State,
    receive
        tick ->
            NewX = X+1,
            NewY = Y+1,
            NewZ = Z+1,
            NewState = {NewX, NewY, NewZ},
            loop(NewState);
        {get_product, From} ->
            Product = X * Y * Z,
            From ! Product,
            loop(State);
        _ ->
            io:format("Unknown message received.~n"),
            loop(State)
    end.

get_product() ->
    server ! {get_product, self()},
    receive
        Product ->
            Product
    end.

tick() ->
    server ! tick.
```

From within the Erlang shell:

```
1> c(lab).
{ok,lab}
2> lab:start().
true
3> lab:get_product().
1
4> lab:tick().       
tick
5> lab:get_product().
8
6> lab:tick().       
tick
7> lab:tick().
tick
8> lab:get_product().
64
```